# Get the last selected item in multiselect box

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have add a ListBox from Active X Controls in my Excel File and made it a multi select box with checkboxes.

[image]

I have also added a selection change event in the VB script against this list box.

```
Sub lstMultiSelectBox_Change()
  If blnCheck = False Then
     CheckAll
  End If
End Sub
```

Now what I am struggling to find is that which item was last checked. With this information I want to implement Select All and Un Select All feature in this list box.

Comment: Why not just check if the select all option is checked or not? For example if the Select All is always the first item in the list then you know it's index is 0 (if it's the second item then it's 1 etc)so you can check if `Listbox1.Selected(0) = True Then`

Comment: Otherwise if you don't know it's position then you need to loop through `For i = 0 To ListCount - 1` to check if it's selected AND if the `.List(i)` = "Select All".

Comment: But, for the purpose you explained, why not using the @Simon's good idea of using `Listbox1.Selected(0)`? In your case `Selected(1)`, since there is another empty first line... Then un select it (in the same code sequence), in order to not be triggered all the time.

Comment: The problem with the suggested solution is that when i am going to click any other item in the list the same logic is going to run, for example i select the Item "SO" in the list the same logic will check if the SelectAll item is checked or not if its not checked then it is going to uncheck all the items in the list. So i want to implement this logic only in case when Select All item is clicked.

Comment: I actually solved my Select / Un Select All problem with a dirty trick that whenever I am opening the list box i am storing the value of Select All in a variable and on change I am comparing that variable's value with the current state of Select All item this tells me if the item that was changed was Select All or not. But i was hoping to get a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: If the Select All stays in the same place then my suggestion is probably the quickest and easiest method you could use. I'm not sure if you understand how quick VBA is but adding that if statement will literally not cost your computer any resources. I would say it would take less than 0.00001 seconds for it to calculate it. You're overthinking it.

Comment: The best thing you could actually do is make the Select All a separate button outside of the listbox. This would make things a lot easier for you as well.

Comment: Do you want seeing a working code **returning the last selected item in the list box**, or a solution to know if "Select All" was last selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make `ListBox1_Change` event returning the last selected list box value, you can use the solution. It can detect the selected value, independent of its position in the list:

1. Create a `Private` variable on top of the sheet module where the list box exists (in the declarations area):

```
Private colS As New Collection
```

2. Then copy the next adapted event code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            If colS.Count = 0 Then
                colS.Add ListBox1.List(i), ListBox1.List(i)
            Else
                If Not itExists(colS, ListBox1.List(i)) Then
                    colS.Add ListBox1.List(i), ListBox1.List(i)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If itExists(colS, ListBox1.List(i)) Then
                colS.Remove ListBox1.List(i): Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If colS.Count > 0 Then MsgBox colS(colS.Count)
End Sub
```

If you want it triggering only if the selected value is "Select All", then replace the last event code line with something like:

```
 If colS.Count > 0 Then 
   If colS(colS.Count) = "Select All" then
     'do whatever you need in such a case
     'but, if you try selecting all of lines, in order to avoid the event 
     'being triggered again, you should use 'Application.EnableEvents = False`, before selecting and 'Application.EnableEvents = True` after
   End If
 End If
```

The simplest solution should be the one suggested in the first comment:

```
 If Listbox1.Selected(1) = True Then
   'do whatever you need
 End If
```

But, in order to make it working as it should, the line "Select All" **should be the second of the list**...

Comment: I actually did something similar to this I created a bool variable and stored the value of SelectAll when i open the list box. And when the Listbox change is fired i just compare the old value with existing value this way i find out if the selected item was Select All or not.